# How could I write into a document instantly in loop(javascript)?

Tags: javascript

```js
while(something)
{
setTimeout(function()
{
var btn = document.createElement("P");
       var t = document.createTextNode(str);  //str->string variable
    btn.appendChild(t);
       document.body.appendChild(btn);
    },1000);
}
```

My program supposed to write out the str variable every time immediately after the delay but it only writes it out at the end.
Any solution to make it instant?

Comment: That's what set time out does.

Comment: You actually have any idea what this code is doing?

Comment: Remove the setTimeout if you want it instant....

Comment: Not sure about te textnode and the appendchild but I am asking for help.

Comment: @LajosDeák why do you have the setTimeout?

Comment: I have the settimeout because I want a delay between each write.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking. If the answers are not what you are looking for could you explain further?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might use `setInterval` instead. This will call your function every Xms until you cancel it.

```
if (something) {
    var interval = setInterval(function() {
        if (!something) {
            clearInterval(interval);
        }
        var btn = document.createElement("P");
        var t = document.createTextNode(str);  //str->string variable
        btn.appendChild(t);
        document.body.appendChild(btn);
    }, 1000);
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to run immediately then your going to have call it before the `setTimeout` I would make the code you run into a named function:

```
        function doSomething() {
     var btn = document.createElement("P");
 var t = document.createTextNode(str); //str->string variable    
btn.appendChild(t); document.body.appendChild(btn); 
         }
```

Call it: `doSomething();`

And them set the timeout!

`setTimeout(doSomething, 100);`

Or maybe use setInterval instead of setTimeout.

All together:

```
function doSomething() {
var btn = document.createElement("P");
     var t = document.createTextNode(str); //str->string variable    
    btn.appendChild(t); document.body.appendChild(btn); 
 };
doSomething();
setTimeout(doSomething, 100);
```